# C# OLEDB query not properly populating elements

Tags: c#, oledb

I have a query that gives the proper result in MS Access:

```
Select MADW_CNT_D.* FROM MADW_CNT_D
```

| LabNumber | cntSOC |
| --- | --- |
| 1E10080-01 | 50 |
| 1E10080-02 | 0 |

LabNumber is a string and cntSOC is an integer. The value "50" is the correct cntSOC value corresponding to LabNumber 1E10080-01.

I have a C# method:

```
        public static List<object[]> ReadQueryToList(string connectString, string query)
        {
            List<object[]> list = new List<object[]>();
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataReader oleReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (oleReader.Read())
                        {
                            object[] arr = new object[oleReader.FieldCount];
                            oleReader.GetValues(arr);
                            list.Add(arr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

When I submit the same query to the method I get:

| LabNumber | cntSOC |
| --- | --- |
| 1E10080-01 | **0** |
| 1E10080-02 | 0 |

The value "0" is incorrect.

What's wrong with my method?

Comment: What does the debugger show you is in `arr` when you stop there and inspect it?

Comment: The debugger shows: Name:Value:Type: arr {object[2]} object[]
 [0] "1E10080-01" object {string}
 [1] 0 object {int} ... (Just like the List<object> the method returns.

Comment: What is the exact value of `query`?

Comment: Select MADW_CNT_D.* FROM MADW_CNT_D

Comment: Same issue with: "Select LabNumber, cntSOC FROM MADW_CNT_D;"

Comment: Trust what you are looking at then.  You have 0, not 50.  Do make sure you are looking at the correct database.